# How to add blank line between lines from different ip groups

Tags: text, awk

I have a file localhost.txt of the form (ip,info):

```
192.168.1.8 host name alex
192.168.1.8 macaddress 1354321313
192.168.1.8 time 04:18
192.168.1.20 date 6/2/2012
192.168.1.20 host name riko
192.168.1.11 year 2014
192.168.1.11 host name cr7
192.168.1.11 shared files off
192.168.1.11 time 12:84
```

I want output result as:

```
192.168.1.8 host name alex
192.168.1.8 macaddress 1354321313
192.168.1.8 time 04:18

192.168.1.20 date 6/2/2012
192.168.1.20 host name riko

192.168.1.11 year 2014
192.168.1.11 host name cr7
192.168.1.11 shared files off
192.168.1.11 time 12:84
```

i tried this

```
awk '{if(NR > 1 && $2 != prev_two){printf "\n";} prev_two=$2; print $0}' localhost.txt >> result.txt
```

and this

```
awk 'prev != $2 {print ""} {print; prev=$2}' localhost.txt >> result.txt
```

but dosent work

i have been read this

[Add blank line between lines from different groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380447/how-to-add-blank-line-between-lines-from-different-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$ awk '{if(NR > 1 && $1 != prev_two){printf "\n";} prev_two=$1; print $0}' localhost.txt >> result.txt
$ cat result.txt
192.168.1.8 host name alex
192.168.1.8 macaddress 1354321313
192.168.1.8 time 04:18

192.168.1.20 date 6/2/2012
192.168.1.20 host name riko

192.168.1.11 year 2014
192.168.1.11 host name cr7
192.168.1.11 shared files off
192.168.1.11 time 12:84
```

should work. It's the first field you want to group by, not the second (hence the `$1`).

Comment: Or `'NR>1 && $1!=prev {print ""}; {prev=$1; print}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `awk`

```
awk '$1!=a && NR>1 {$0=RS$0} {a=$1} 1' file
192.168.1.8 host name alex
192.168.1.8 macaddress 1354321313
192.168.1.8 time 04:18

192.168.1.20 date 6/2/2012
192.168.1.20 host name riko

192.168.1.11 year 2014
192.168.1.11 host name cr7
192.168.1.11 shared files off
192.168.1.11 time 12:84
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an one liner usnig `awk`, but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

prev=""
while read -r line
do
   cur=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
   if [[ "$prev" == "" ]]; then
     prev="$cur"
   elif [[ "$prev" != "$cur" ]]; then
     echo ""
   fi
   echo "$line"
   prev="$cur"
done
```

Comment: thank you..i think awk is very very fast..and thank you very much :)