# How to add newline after last repeated string in specific column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to add a newline after the last repeated string in a column. This is one of the steps I need to tailor the output of a command I frequently use, to be more soothing on the eyes.

Eg. The output I've arranged is currently in this form:

```
10.12   null   machineA
19.13   null   machineA
12.11   null   machineA
12.13   null   machineB
14.14   null   machineB
11.17   null   machineC
17.13   null   machineC
16.16   null   machineC
```

I'd like to view the output as:

```
10.12   null   machineA
19.13   null   machineA
12.11   null   machineA

12.13   null   machineB
14.14   null   machineB

11.17   null   machineC
17.13   null   machineC
16.16   null   machineC
```

I assume sed or awk is my friend. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just replace `$2` with `$NF` in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380552/3832970).

Comment: Apologies for the dupe. Didn't find that solution despite searching for quite a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, the file is sorted by 3rd column, you can use prev and curr variables and print the results

```
 awk ' { c=$3; if(c!=p && NR>1) { print "" } print ; p=c } ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat kalam.txt
10.12   null   machineA
19.13   null   machineA
12.11   null   machineA
12.13   null   machineB
14.14   null   machineB
11.17   null   machineC
17.13   null   machineC
16.16   null   machineC

$ awk ' { c=$3; if(c!=p && NR>1) { print "" } print ; p=c } ' kalam.txt
10.12   null   machineA
19.13   null   machineA
12.11   null   machineA

12.13   null   machineB
14.14   null   machineB

11.17   null   machineC
17.13   null   machineC
16.16   null   machineC

$
```